# R6016 - not enough space for thread data

Tags: visual-c++

How do I go about debugging "R6016 - not enough space for thread data" in a C++ application.
I've read http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126709  but would like some other input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message is generated by the C Run Time Library, CRT.  Which version of the CRT are you using?  I would start by determining what my call stack was when this error is generated.  You can grep the CRT source code to find every place the error would be returned.  I would also look at any in place in my code that calls TLSAlloc to see what I am putting into thread local storage and why.