# what are the possible root causes for the issue "R6016 - not enough space for thread data"

Tags: windows, multithreading, visual-c++, windows-7, com

I want to know the possible root causes which makes the problem "R6016 - not enough space for thread data" for the application(COM .exe) which i created.

Comment: possible duplicate of [R6016 - not enough space for thread data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928088/r6016-not-enough-space-for-thread-data)

Comment: @zdan I want to know the things which are causing this problem..in that post, no information about what i want..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R6016 - not enough space for thread data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/928088/r6016-not-enough-space-for-thread-data)

Comment: Your question is not specific enough to result in good answers. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.