# Apache crashes with error R6016 not enough space for thread data

Tags: php, c++, apache, apache2

My application works properly except in some cases I get this error

```
R6016 not enough space for thread data
```

So I am now investigating why I get this error. I am not surre If my app is causing this or something in the backend.

Here is a xml from the windows event log of the error

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Application Error" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>100</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-12-17T14:03:36.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>333483</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>MY-PC</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>apache.exe</Data> 
  <Data>2.2.19.0</Data> 
  <Data>4dd7429b</Data> 
  <Data>ntdll.dll</Data> 
  <Data>6.1.7601.17725</Data> 
  <Data>4ec49b8f</Data> 
  <Data>c0000005</Data> 
  <Data>000343d6</Data> 
  </EventData>
```

also here is a helper information

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Windows Error Reporting" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1001</EventID> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-12-17T14:03:45.000000000Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>333484</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>MY-PC</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
- <EventData>
  <Data>3122334836</Data> 
  <Data>1</Data> 
  <Data>APPCRASH</Data> 
  <Data>Not available</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>apache.exe</Data> 
  <Data>2.2.19.0</Data> 
  <Data>4dd7429b</Data> 
  <Data>ntdll.dll</Data> 
  <Data>6.1.7601.17725</Data> 
  <Data>4ec49b8f</Data> 
  <Data>c0000005</Data> 
  <Data>000343d6</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Local\Temp\WERA29B.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml</Data> 
  <Data>C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_SenseWeb.exe_337f61e2ed7abb1fe78d685bd48c832557c6b1_3561c67f</Data> 
  <Data /> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  <Data>8c82cf18-4852-11e2-a5d0-005056c00008</Data> 
  <Data>0</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Why this is happening? What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

On is if you are repeatedly loading and unloading some DLL, causing the system to run out of TLS entries. You should just leave it loaded.

The other is if you are calling [TLSAlloc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/928381/721269) over and over. You should only need to call this a very small number of times.

See [this knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126709) for more information.

Comment: I am loading my custom made dll(COM php) file which is loaded with every php request, could this possibly is causing this error?

Comment: Definitely. If your DLL allocates a TLS entry, constantly unloading and reloading it is fatal if you don't call [TLSFree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686804%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on unload.

Comment: How to prevent this from happening in php? Some method, function etc...??

Comment: It's either the DLL itself not calling `TLSFree` or something repeatedly loading and unloading the DLL. As a workaround, you may want to run a dummy script that just keeps the DLL loaded.

Comment: Can I somehow access the TLS and see what data is there when the crash occurs?

Comment: It's not bad data, it's resource exhaustion. Each time you use the DLL, you are calling `TLSAlloc` and allocating a TLS slot. It is never getting freed.